# Can I install Apache or Wamp on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Will I be able to install Apache web Server or WAMP on windows 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can - I have been running Apache on Windows 8 for months now without any issues:

[image]

The latest version of Apache (2.4.3, released 2012-08-21) can be found here:

- [Win32 MSI](http://apache.skazkaforyou.com//httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8t.msi)
- [Win64 ZIP](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/binaries/httpd-2.4.3-win64.zip)

The latest version of WampServer (2.2E) can be found here:

- [Win32 EXE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/wampserver2.2e/wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-32b.exe/download)
- [Win64 EXE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/wampserver2.2e/wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-x64.exe/download)

Comment: I accepted this as a my answer simply for the screen shot, but both responses where adequate

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will be able to. If you would like a jumpstart and don't feel like installing everything from scratch I would recommend the following:

- [WAMPserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Comment: Awesome! I've used WAMP in the past, and I am downloading the windows 8 evaluation copy now. Curious to see how it's different than Windows 7.